# C# "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"

Tags: c#, .net

Having the same issue i was last week only with inheiriting from the parent class:

```
public ExtendedTime(int Hour, int Minute, String TimeZone) :base(hour, minute)
{

    timeZone = TimeZone;
}//end of ExtendedTime
```

`:base(hour,minute)` is where i have this error.
Says the same problem for both hour and minute.
Now usually I would say that i'm missing something far as a property but i tried that and it didn't do any good sadly.
in the parent class hour and minute are declared as following:

```
    internal int hour;
    internal int minute;
```

And i have setters and getters setup.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're trying to use the *fields* `hour` and `minute` when you probably meant to use the constructor parameters. You can't use fields (or any other instance members) when calling a base class constructor.

Personally I'd change the constructor parameters to have more conventional names:

```
public ExtendedTime(int hour, int minute, String timeZone) : base(hour, minute)
{    
    this.timeZone = timeZone;
}
```

Note that if you made your fields *private* instead of internal, the issue would have been more obvious, as you wouldn't have access to the fields in the first place :)

Comment: Thanks. I've seen the solution for this project and i swear that it was suppose to be case sensitive to the parent class. ^_^

Comment: @allthosemiles: I don't know what you mean... but it *is* case-sensitive, and you still can't use instance members...

Comment: Why can't you use fields when calling a base class constructor? Do you know where to find the documentation on this?

Comment: @Protectorone: You basically can't refer to `this` at all... this is to protect you; the object hasn't been fully initialized yet (in particular, you can't have set any fields declared in this class based on parameters yet).

Comment: @Jon: That makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing your arguments:

```
Hour != hour
Minute != minute
```

Change it to

```
public ExtendedTime(int hour, int minute, string timeZone) : base(hour, minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be having a casing problem (c# is case sensitive), try this:

```
public ExtendedTime(int hour, int minute, String TimeZone) :base(hour, minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, `int Hour, int Minute, String TimeZone` are not proper parameters. Use object names in parameters, not their Class.