# C# Base Constructor Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I'm trying to inherit from a base class but I'm getting an error that I can't figure out. This is the base class:

```
class Item
{
    protected string name;

    public Item(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And this is the inherited class:

```
class ItemToBuy : Item
{
    private int lowPrice;
    private int highPrice;
    private int maxQuantity;

    public ItemToBuy(int lowPrice, int highPrice, int maxQuantity) : base(name)
    {
        this.lowPrice = lowPrice;
        this.highPrice = highPrice;
        this.maxQuantity = maxQuantity;
    }
}
```

The issue is this line:

`public ItemToBuy(int lowPrice, int highPrice, int maxQuantity) : base(name)`

where 'name' is underlined with the error message "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'Item.name'. If I replace it with a string literal the error message isn't there. What am I doing wrong with inheriting the constructor?

Comment: If you don't have a parameter name in the constructor of ItemToBuy, you cannot call the constructor of the base class that requires a name parameter. If you don't have it, then add a constructor to the base class that takes no parameters or change your ItemToBuy constructor to require a name parameter to pass down to the base class

Comment: OK, so think about this for a minute. The base class needs a `name`. Therefore any derived class is going to need to pass a `name` to the base class constructor. It can't just conjure this up out of thin air - either the derived class creates a `name` somehow and passes it to the base class' constructor, or `name` must be an argument of the derived class' constructor and then passed through to the base class' constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817967/c-sharp-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-pr)

Answer (score 4):

your ItemToBuy class does not have any knowledge of "name". 
The way you build the constructor, "name" needs to be a defined string.

Let's say that your constructor looks like this:

```
class ItemToBuy : Item
{
    private int lowPrice;
    private int highPrice;
    private int maxQuantity;

    public ItemToBuy(int lowPrice, int highPrice, int maxQuantity, string name) : base(name)
    {
        this.lowPrice = lowPrice;
        this.highPrice = highPrice;
        this.maxQuantity = maxQuantity;
    }
}
```

this will work because the name parameter is defined.

So, you either do it like that or pass a hardcoded value like you did to make it work.

Comment: Upvoted because this is the only answer that actually explains the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the name in the ctor of the ItemToBuy class too

```
public ItemToBuy(string name ,int lowPrice, int highPrice, int maxQuantity) : base(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ItemToBuy(int lowPrice, int highPrice, int maxQuantity) : base(name)
{
    this.lowPrice = lowPrice;
    this.highPrice = highPrice;
    this.maxQuantity = maxQuantity;
}
```

should be changed to:

```
public ItemToBuy(int lowPrice, int highPrice, int maxQuantity, string name) : base(name)
{
    this.lowPrice = lowPrice;
    this.highPrice = highPrice;
    this.maxQuantity = maxQuantity;
}
```

*You need to specify the `name` parameter in the constructor, as per my code above.*

Comment: Stylistically, I would put the name parameter first in the ItemToBuy constructor.

Comment: It would depend on context as to whether that makes sense, but yep @Polyfun that is certainly valid. `name` can be at any position (not necessarily the first or last).

Answer (score 0):

you need to receive the name in the constructor of ItemToBuy:

```
public ItemToBuy(int lowPrice, int highPrice, int maxQuantity,string name) : base(name)
```